# Can I access the 4 addresses available in the mac header of the Wireless 802.11 packets?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am writing a module that hooks a function on OUTPUT hook of the kernel netfilter. I want to access the complete information inside the mac header of the packet esp all the 4 addresses or in some cases 3 addresses of the mac header. I am using the `struct sk_buff` to get the packet's fields but it does not give any fields other than

```
ethhdr = (struct ethhdr *)skb_mac_header(skb);
eth_hdr(skb)->h_dest;
eth_hdr(skb)->h_source;
eth_hdr(skb)->h_proto;
```

these fields.

Can anyone give me some code that can extract them at the OUTPUT hook of the netfilter in Linux where this would be added as a hook function? Or if this is possible anyways?

Comment: What happens if you cast to `ieee80211_hdr` instead ?

Comment: I have seen the documentation for it, looks like it can work.I'  report back if it works.

Comment: I got the code, but i don't know how to print it. When i use statement like `printk(KERN_INFO "The first address is %pM: \n", ieee->addr1);` the kernel goes under panic mode. Any suggestions how to look at the values please?